# Equivalent of %~dp0 (retrieving source file name) in sh

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

I'm converting some Windows batch files to Unix scripts using sh. I have problems because some behavior is dependent on the %~dp0 macro available in batch files.

Is there any sh equivalent to this? Any way to obtain the directory where the executing script lives?

Comment: it seems when designing bash this feature wasn't a concern to go for...

Comment: Note that this question asks explicitly about `sh` -- there are a lot of answers that talk about bash instead, but they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

The problem (for you) with `$0` is that it is set to whatever command line was use to invoke the script, not the location of the script itself. This can make it difficult to get the full path of the directory containing the script which is what you get from `%~dp0` in a Windows batch file.

For example, consider the following script, `dollar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

If you'd run it you'll get the following output:

```
# ./dollar.sh
./dollar.sh
# /tmp/dollar.sh
/tmp/dollar.sh
```

So to get the fully qualified directory name of a script I do the following:

```
cd `dirname $0`
SCRIPTDIR=`pwd`
cd -
```

This works as follows:

1. `cd` to the directory of the script, using either the relative or absolute path from the command line.
2. Gets the absolute path of this directory and stores it in `SCRIPTDIR`.
3. Goes back to the previous working directory using "`cd -`".

Comment: If changing the working directory is undesirable I added another appraoch.

Comment: The the script is in the path and not being called directly, then $0 will be just the name of the script and this method will not work.

Comment: So throw in a call to 'which' as well, and problem solved. (which tells you the full path to a command, but what most people don't seem to know is that it echoes back the full path if it's already absolute.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can! It's in the arguments. :)

look at

```
${0}
```

combining that with

```
{$var%Pattern}
Remove from $var  the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
```

what you want is just

```
${0%/*}
```

I recommend the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)
(that is also where the above information is from).
Especiall the part on [Converting DOS Batch Files to Shell Scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html)
might be useful for you. :)

If I have misunderstood you, you may have to combine that with the output of "pwd". Since it only contains the path the script was called with!
Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
called_path=${0%/*}
stripped=${called_path#[^/]*}
real_path=`pwd`$stripped
echo "called path: $called_path"
echo "stripped: $stripped"
echo "pwd: `pwd`"
echo "real path: $real_path
```

This needs some work though.
I recommend using Dave Webb's approach unless that is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

In bash under linux you can get the full path to the command with:

```
readlink /proc/$$/fd/255
```

and to get the directory:

```
dir=$(dirname $(readlink /proc/$$/fd/255))
```

It's ugly, but I have yet to find another way.

Comment: could you expand the explanation over why this is better than other proposed answers in the case when the script is in the path and thus called indirectly, and how does it work, what does it depend on (I expect things like `$$` of bash, and a unix file-system, please note there is bash on cygwin or mingw that can be started without a posix-compatible filesystem structure at hand)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
${0%/*}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find the path for a script that was being sourced from another script. And that was my problem, when sourcing the text just gets copied into the calling script, so $0 always returns information about the calling script.

I found a workaround, that only works in bash, $BASH_SOURCE always has the info about the script in which it is referred to. Even if the script is sourced it is correctly resolved to the original (sourced) script.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is this one:
[How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

> It is important to realize that in the general case, **this problem has no solution**. Any approach you might have heard of, and any approach that will be detailed below, has flaws and will only work in specific cases. First and foremost, try to avoid the problem entirely by not depending on the location of your script!
>
> Before we dive into solutions, let's clear up some misunderstandings. It is important to understand that:
> **Your script does not actually have a location**! Wherever the bytes end up coming from, **there is no "one canonical path" for it.** Never.
> $0 is NOT the answer to your problem. If you think it is, you can either stop reading and write more bugs, or you can accept this and read on.
> ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a *script* can get the shell file real path when executed or sourced.
Tested in **bash, zsh, ksh, dash**.

BTW: you shall clean the verbose code by yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "---------------- GET SELF PATH ----------------"
echo "NOW \$(pwd) >>> $(pwd)"
ORIGINAL_PWD_GETSELFPATHVAR=$(pwd)

echo "NOW \$0 >>> $0"
echo "NOW \$_ >>>  $_"
echo "NOW \${0##*/} >>> ${0##*/}"

if test -n "$BASH"; then
    echo "RUNNING IN BASH..."
    SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
elif test -n "$ZSH_NAME"; then
    echo "RUNNING IN ZSH..."
    SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=${(%):-%x}
elif test -n "$KSH_VERSION"; then
    echo "RUNNING IN KSH..."
    SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=${.sh.file}
else
    echo "RUNNING IN DASH OR OTHERS ELSE..."
    SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=$(lsof -p $$ -Fn0 | tr -d '\0' | grep "${0##*/}" | tail -1 | sed 's/^[^\/]*//g')
fi

echo "EXECUTING FILE PATH: $SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR"

cd "$(dirname "$SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR")" || return 1

SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR=$(basename "$SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR")

# Iterate down a (possible) chain of symlinks as lsof of macOS doesn't have -f option.
while [ -L "$SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR" ]; do
    SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=$(readlink "$SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR")
    cd "$(dirname "$SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR")" || return 1
    SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR=$(basename "$SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR")
done

# Compute the canonicalized name by finding the physical path
# for the directory we're in and appending the target file.
SH_SELF_PATH_DIR_RESULT=$(pwd -P)
SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR=$SH_SELF_PATH_DIR_RESULT/$SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR
echo "EXECUTING REAL PATH: $SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR"
echo "EXECUTING FILE DIR: $SH_SELF_PATH_DIR_RESULT"

cd "$ORIGINAL_PWD_GETSELFPATHVAR" || return 1
unset ORIGINAL_PWD_GETSELFPATHVAR
unset SH_FILE_RUN_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR
unset SH_FILE_RUN_BASENAME_GETSELFPATHVAR
unset SH_FILE_REAL_PATH_GETSELFPATHVAR
echo "---------------- GET SELF PATH ----------------"
# USE $SH_SELF_PATH_DIR_RESULT BEBLOW
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for bash shell:

```
dir=$(dirname $(readlink -m $BASH_SOURCE))
```

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(dirname $(readlink -m $BASH_SOURCE))
```

Run test:

```
$ ./somedir/test.sh 
/tmp/somedir
$ source ./somedir/test.sh 
/tmp/somedir
$ bash ./somedir/test.sh 
/tmp/somedir
$ . ./somedir/test.sh 
/tmp/somedir
```

Comment: You're missing some quotes -- try this if your file comes from a directory with spaces (or especially an `*` with spaces on both sides) in its name, and the given code won't behave well. It would be more correct as `dir=$(dirname "$(readlink -m "$BASH_SOURCE")")`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried $0 before, namely:

> dirname $0

and it just returns "." even when the script is being sourced by another script:

> . ../somedir/somescript.sh