# Get sourced filename in busybox ash

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

The ash shell in busybox doesn't seem to implement any of the standard ways to get the filename that's being sourced.  For instance:

> `testo`:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env -S busybox ash
> echo hello whorl
> echo using source
> source ./sourceme
> echo using .
> . ./sourceme
> ```

> `sourceme`:
>
> ```
> echo underscore $_
> echo bs $BASH_SOURCE
> echo zero $0
> ```

> ```
> # ./testo 
> hello whorl
> using source
> underscore ./testo
> bs
> zero ./testo
> using .
> underscore ./testo
> bs
> zero ./testo
> ```

I need something to put in `sourceme` that will get its own name/path.

Answer (score 1):

[This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207959/equivalent-of-dp0-in-sh/70477052#70477052) contains a very clever way to accomplish this.  I've adapted their solution here - insert this line into `sourceme`:

```
echo lsof `lsof -p $$ -Fn | tail -n1 | sed 's!^[^/]*!!g'``
```

And you get:

```
lsof /absolute/path/to/sourceme
```

Note: since we're talking about busybox here, this is an implementation of the above using busybox's `lsof`:

```
lsof | grep '^'$$ | tail -n1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

Note: if anyone finds a way to do this using some builtin mechanism from `busybox ash`, post an answer and I'll change the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: Have you considered getting the list of open files direct from procfs (which is to say, from a `readlink` in the directory `/proc/self/fd`)? I'm not sure what value, if any, `lsof` is adding here. (Also, asking `lsof` to NUL-delimit output but then immediately converting away from NULs is just weird).

Comment: ...ahh, the "why" is support for MacOS (which doesn't have `/proc/self/fd`). If you aren't on a Mac, though, I'd probably avoid that hairball of a command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I hadn't considered that.  Honestly I didn't even really look at what was inside the `lsof` line, but now I sort of want to implement the lighter weight version with procfs.  I'll update when I get it.  Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Couldn't get a procfs solution to work myself (not using a Mac).  But I was able to clean up the command a little.  I see why the original author of the line was using null as the field termination character, but it isn't necessary.  Updating the answer with slightly streamlined version of the one-liner.

Comment: So, the place I erred in giving you advice was suggesting `/proc/self/fd` instead of `/proc/$$/fd` -- the former will give you the file descriptors open in `readlink` or `ls` or whatever other tool you have the shell starting; the latter gives you the file descriptors open in the shell itself.

Comment: Ah ok that makes a lot more sense.  I'm actually not going to implement as I'm happy with the lsof solution.